# POSTING data from Angular UI bootstrap modal window to PHP

Tags: mysql, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-modal

I have a angular-ui modal, that is controlled with below controller:

```
var emailModal = angular.module('myApp.emailModal', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls']);

emailModal.controller('ModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModal', function ($scope, $uibModal) {

  $scope.open = function () {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'components/emailModal/emailModalView.html',
      backdrop: true,
      controller: 'modalInstanceCtrl'
    });
  }
}]);

emailModal.controller('modalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, $http) {
  //create blank object to handle form data.
  $scope.user = {};
  //calling our submit function.
  $scope.submitForm = function() {
    //posting data to php file
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'components/emailModal/emailInsert.php',
      data: $scope.user, //forms user object
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
        .success(function(data) {
          if (data.errors) {
            //showing errors.
            $scope.errorEmail = data.errors.email;
          } else {
            $scope.message = data.message;
          }
        });
  };
});
```

This is the actual modal view:

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Register</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>E-Mail Address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email address" />
        <span ng-show="errorEmail">{{errorEmail}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Modal loads with no problem, bute once clicked to submit, nothing happens. I get no error once so ever in the console. What am I doing wrong? This is my PHP file, as well:

```
$errors = array();
$data = array();
// Getting posted data and decodeing json
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

// checking for blank values.

if (empty($_POST['email']))
    $errors['email'] = 'E-Mail erforderlich.';

if (!empty($errors)) {
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
} else {
    $data['message'] = 'The data should now be inserted into database!';
}
// response back.
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

EDIT 1.

The event is triggered in Dev Tools - Network.

This is what I get:

Request URL: http://localhost:63342/url-to/emailInsert.php
Request method: POST
Remote address: 127.0.0.1:63342
Status code: 200 OK
Version HTTP/1.1

The page is not reloading on submit, at all, there is no error in Dev Tools - Console. It gives a OK status even though the email has not been ineserted into input, therefore it should print an error, which it doesn't do.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Need more feedback than just *"nothing happens"*. Is request made...if so what is status in dev tools network?  is `submitForm ()` firing at all? is page reloading? ... provide as much troubleshooting info as possible

Comment: also add an error handler... it's cases like this you need it, not to mention normal traffic flow

Comment: I have just edited my previous post. Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: You need validation rules on the element to avoid it sending empty. As for 200 ... that's a big step up from `nothing happens` . In those requests in network can also see exactly what gets returned in response body. Should set a content type header in php or datatype in $http if json isn't being parsed to pass to `data.errors` in success. Also helpful sometimes to send back extra data from server while debugging the php. For example to make sure some conditional is working.

Comment: OK, what I get now is that I get an error once I submit the form with email field blank, but when I submit the email, it doesn't return the success message. Can I ask you to be more specific on what I should do, to get the results you are referring to. I'm newbie with angular, so any help is more than welcome.

Comment: get really familiar with what's inside that request in dev tools network...can see exactly what is sent also. I don't see where message would go. Also don't know if modal is closing or not. If you need to pass data back from modal controller need to follow docs example and pass it back in `close()` and receive it in `result` promise in other controller